# mapreduce: customize task outofmemory failure

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map-only job which operates as one task per file. Sometimes a file  causes task out-of-memory type exceptions.

Imagine an input directory has 10 files. Therefore the job will have 10 tasks. Now imagine 9 "good" files will succeed and 1 "bad" file cause out-of-memory exception.

Ideally I want the one "bad" file to move to a quarantine directory. The 9 "good" files write output. The job succeeds with warnings in the logs.

Partial success can come from using `mapreduce.reduce.failures.maxpercent` setting which is good.

But how to copy the "bad file" to quarantine when the container fails with out-of-memory?

I was thinking a custom FileOutputCommitter overriding the taskAbort method would provide the proper hook.

Anyone else done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find the answer in job history server [rest api](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html), but unfortunately task attempts do not store info about their input paths.

If you won't find a better solution, you can do this:

1. create a special directory on hdfs for your job
2. in mapper setup method get input split name and store it in a special marker file inside this directory
3. when mapper finishes successfully, in cleanup method delete this marker file
4. after job finishes, check the directory and process bad files which names are there

Comment: I cannot find more direct approaches documented beyond your proposal. I think this is straightforward and quite clever thank you!